# Let shinyapps.io run shiny app daily automatically

Tags: r, shiny

I uploaded an app to my shinyapps.io account, and I want to let it run daily automatically. I added `invalidateLater(86400000)` and it works locally (after the app becomes idle for a while, it automatically runs again), but when uploaded to shinyapps.io, it doesn't work. I close the app, and wait for a day, and it wasn't ran automatically. I checked the log file and it confirmed that the app did not run.

Is there any way to let the shiny app run on shinyapps.io automatically without leaving the app open in the browser?

Comment: Have you tried modifying `Worker Settings` in  advanced tab of application settings at [shinyapp.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/) ?

Comment: I can't find anything related to setting a schedule to run the app in advanced settings. I'm on a free account though. Will upgrading it give the ability to do that?

Comment: pardon about earlier `link`, as you can see [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/217592947-What-are-the-limits-of-the-shinyapps-io-Free-plan-) , _active hours_ in free account is only 25 hours, so application is active only for 15min.